# How Can I Upload Folder or Directory using Mega API in C#?

Tags: c#, api, upload, cloud

I was able to upload a file in Mega cloud storage using its API client. But I can't find a way to upload whole folder to cloud using c#. Is there any module that can finish this job?

Comment: If you're using this https://www.nuget.org/packages/MegaApiClient I don't see a method to upload a directory but you can do it by yourself by creating the target folder and then uploading the files (recursively)

Comment: Yes I am using MegaApi Client. Can you link me example how to upload all the files in folder without sending whole directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Paolo I have found a method from the link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6fb488ac-5171-4af6-ad9c-5d9c29173a05/upload-all-files-and-folders-using-c?forum=aspcsharp

```
void RecureDirectory(DirectoryInfo directory)
{
    CreateFolder("ftp://192.168.149.1/"+directory.Name);
    FileInfo[] files = null;
    DirectoryInfo[] subDirectories = null;
    //first, process all the files directly under this folder
    files = directory.GetFiles("*.*");
    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            string fileName = file.Name;
            FileStream fileStream = file.OpenRead();
            byte[] fileContents = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            fileStream.Read(fileContents, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
            CopyCorresondFilesForFolderCreated(ViewState["FolderName"].ToString(),fileName, fileContents);
            ViewState["FolderName"] = null;
        }
        //now find all the subdirectories under this directory
        subDirectories = directory.GetDirectories();
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirectories)
        {
            //resurvise call for each subdirectory

            RecureDirectory(dirInfo);
        }
    }
}
```